# MySQL duplicate columns values when using left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables and insert:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klik_zona` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `klik` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `klik_zona` (`kode_zona`, `klik`) VALUES
(1, 45);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tampil_zona` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tanggal` date NOT NULL,
  `tampil` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`,`tanggal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tampil_zona` (`kode_zona`, `tanggal`, `tampil`) VALUES
(1, '2014-03-16', 100),
(1, '2014-03-17', 23);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zona_iklan` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `zona_iklan` (`kode_zona`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
```

I have a query below:

```
SELECT z.kode_zona, SUM( tz.tampil ) , SUM( kz.klik )
FROM zona_iklan z
LEFT JOIN tampil_zona tz ON tz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
LEFT JOIN klik_zona kz ON kz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
GROUP BY z.kode_zona
```

but it give result:

```
kode_zona   SUM(tz.tampil)  SUM(kz.klik)    
1                123        90
2                NULL      NULL
3                NULL      NULL
```

I hope to get result:

```
kode_zona   SUM(tz.tampil)  SUM(kz.klik)    
1                123        45
2                NULL      NULL
3                NULL      NULL
```

can anyone help me, please. How to make query so that it's showed like that i hope to get..

Thanks.

Comment: use group by to avoid dupicates

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT distinct z.kode_zona, SUM(distinct tz.tampil ) , SUM(distinct kz.klik )
FROM zona_iklan z
LEFT JOIN tampil_zona tz ON z.kode_zona = tz.kode_zona 
LEFT JOIN klik_zona kz ON z.kode_zona = kz.kode_zona
GROUP BY z.kode_zona
```

I think, it's what you want

Comment: Try adding `(1, '2014-03-18', 23);`, won't give the correct result (still 123, should be 146).

Comment: when I change insert table to:

Answer (score 0):

```
select kode_zona,
       sum(case when splitter = 'tampil' then summer else 0 end) as sum_tampil,
       sum(case when splitter = 'klik' then summer else 0 end) as sum_klik
  from (SELECT 'tampil' as splitter, z.kode_zona, SUM(tz.tampil) as summer
          FROM zona_iklan z
          LEFT JOIN tampil_zona tz
            ON tz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
         GROUP BY z.kode_zona
        union all
        SELECT 'klik' as splitter, z.kode_zona, SUM(kz.klik) as summer
          FROM zona_iklan z
          LEFT JOIN klik_zona kz
            ON kz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
         GROUP BY z.kode_zona) x
 group by kode_zona
```

SQL Fiddle test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8f4f2/15/0

Answer (score 0):

Another idea...

```
SELECT x.kode_zona
     , y.type
     , COALESCE(SUM(y.value),0) ttl
  FROM zona_iklan x
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT kode_zona, 'klik' type, klik value FROM klik_zona
       UNION
       SELECT kode_zona, 'tampil' , tampil value FROM tampil_zona
     ) y
    ON y.kode_zona = x.kode_zona
 GROUP
    BY x.kode_zona
     , y.type;
```